# Is there a public repository for ExoPlayer snapshots?

Tags: android, exoplayer

Is there a way to run up-to-date snapshots of the [Exoplayer library](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/dev-v2) (dev-v2 branch)? I couldn't find a link to a public snapshot repository so I'm guessing no, but I wanted to confirm.

Comment: What do you mean by a public snapshot repository ?

Comment: @superman Some libraries (such as [Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit)) have a build bot that builds the most recent version of a branch every time a commit is pushed to it and posts that build in a "snapshot" Maven repo.